# update existing record in MySQL when inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a `MySQL` database containing below fields:

```
cid
number
date
code
```

`cid` and `number` are keys.
Every day data from another table from the first `date` is inserted to this table with a `php` script. 
`code` field is updatable in source table and I want to update the existing records in destination table if code has changed when inserting records to destination. I mean I do not want to insert updated data as a new row but updating current record.

How can I do this?

Comment: I kind of get what you want. So what's the problem?

Comment: @BeetleJuice I do not know how to update existing row when inserting updated data in MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

You do this by using MySQL's `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

For this to work, you must set a `UNIQUE` index so that MySQL produces an error (because record exists) and then it moves on to the `UPDATE` part.

In your case, I assume that this key would be `UNIQUE(cid, number, date)`.

Given your current table, query would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table_name 

(cid, number, date, code) 

VALUES 

(1, 2, '2016-08-09', 'code') 

ON DUPLICATE KEY SET code = 'code';
```

Adjust column names and values accordingly.

[Documentation about ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score -3):

```
IF EXISTS...
THEN
UPDATE ... SET ....
ELSE 
INSERT INTO ...
```

With Stored Procedures.